# Basic question with folding and foldmethod=indent

Tags: folding

I am confused about folding. I am trying to use the `foldmethod=indent` method, and my setup is as follows:

[image]

Now when I try to close all folders with `zC` I get this, which is as expected:

[image]

However when I go to the line 2 and do `zo` I get the whole file again:

[image]

I was hoping to only see one level of folding as per the documentation, ie like this:

[image]

Why is  that ? (I am showing the whole on my vimrc in the first screenshot)

Comment: I think it's because you didn't close the nested ones. Close them all first (`zC` may work for this but don't quote me...might have to close them individually) then try it.

Comment: I have just tried and yes it does, but it is a bit tedious to close all subfolders manually first - is this not what 'zC' is supposed to do ?

Comment: Oh, for `zC` it might be that you need to have the cursor on top of the deepest fold. Yeah...that seems to be the  trick.

Comment: yes it does - many thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the folds that are nested inside the one you can see closing are still open. That has to do with the way `zC` works.

I had to look at the docs myself to figure this out. (I'm still a bit clumsy with folds having only recently started using them regularly.)

Here's what it says...

> Close all folds under the cursor recursively. Folds that don't contain the cursor line are unchanged.

I find that second sentence to be a bit vague but after a bit of experimentation I observed the following...

You simply need to put the cursor on or within the deepest fold. Then `zC` will close folds from that point on up.

Alternatively, you can go the scorched earth route and close all folds in the buffer with `zM`. No  need to worry about cursor position with that one. :)